# Proof of injectivity - linear transformation given by $\vec x \mapsto \vec a \times \vec x + \vec x$

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a linear mapping $ A: R^3 \to R^3.$ The vector $\vec {a} \not= \vec 0$. $ A$ is defined like this: $ A: \vec {x} \to \vec {a} \times \vec {x} + \vec {x}$.

Proof of injectivity that I do not understand: 
Suppose the images of $\vec {x} $ and $\vec{y}$ are equal: $A\vec{x} = A\vec{y}.$
Then we have $(\vec{x} - \vec{y}) \times \vec{a} = \vec{x} - \vec{y}.$ Shouldn't that be $\vec{y} - \vec{x}$? 
The proof goes on like this: from the last equation ask yourself which vector is orthogonal to itself? Because  $\vec {a} \not= \vec 0$, we have $\vec{x} - \vec{y} = 0$. Where did this came from? I do not understand the operations.
Because of the last equation we have $\vec{x} = \vec{y}$. That is why $A$ is injective.
Please can someone explain this to me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that $a\times b=-b\times a$, so $Ax=By$ means $a\times x+x=a\times y+y$, i.e., $a\times (x-y)=-(x-y)\times a=y-x$. Now $x-y=0$ because of the definition of the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is linear, you just need to show that, if $A(x)=0$, then $x=0$.

If $A(x)=0$, then $-x=a\times x$, so if you do the scalar product with $x$ you get
$$
-x\cdot x=(a\times x)\cdot x=a\cdot(x\times x)=0
$$
because of the identities $(u\times v)\cdot w=u\cdot(v\times w)$ and $v\times v=0$.

Can you go on?

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Thank you so much.